# How to make ajax false for single field in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to do some `AJAX` validation on my `ActiveForm`, but I want to make `AJAX` validation false for a single field.

How should I do that in Yii2?

My code for single field:

```
<?= $form->field($modelChangePassword, 'CurrentPassword',
   [        
      'options'=>['enableAjaxValidation' => false])->textInput(['placeholder'=>Yii::t('frontend/changePassword','CurrentPasswordPlaceholderText')
    ])
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?= $form->field($modelChangePassword, 'CurrentPassword',
   ['enableAjaxValidation' => false])->textInput(['placeholder'=>Yii::t('frontend/changePassword','CurrentPasswordPlaceholderText')
    ])
    ?>
```